# cppcheck specify directory of files to process but not report errors about

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I have a project with structure like this:

```
/path/to/project/source/library/
/path/to/project/tests/
```

If I run

```
cppcheck --xml-version=2 --enable=all /path/to/project/source/library
```

I get a bunch of "unused function" errors for files in `source/library/`, but there are calls to those functions from files in `tests/`. Is there a way to tell `cppcheck` to parse files in a directory like `tests/` but not report errors about those files themselves?

Answer (score 1):

--suppress Allows you to suppress errors in certain files

Try something like --suppress=*:*tests*

Comment: So you're saying to actually run `cppcheck` on the `project/` directory rather than just the `project/source/library` directory? like `cppcheck --xml-version=2 --enable=all --suppress=*:tests /path/to/project/`? I can imagine a more complicated folder structure that wouldn't allow this (like if there was something else at `project/source/other/`, then I'd have to suppress everything but the `source/library/` path, which would quickly get unmanageable in a big project.

Comment: You can also suppress the unused warnings. If your project is big you are mostly only interested in the serious errors